# How to access the following list and dictionary values in Python3?

Tags: python, json

```json
{
   "list":[
      {
         "a":1,
         "b":2,
         "c":3,
         "d":{
            "d1":10,
            "d2":20,
            "d3":30
         },
         "e":4,
         "f":5,
         "g":[
            {
               "g1":100,
               "g2":200,
               "g3":300
            }
         ],
         "h":6
      }
   ]
}
```

I want to access `d1`, `e`, `g1`, `h`. How can I do it?

Comment: Is this a JSON string?

Comment: Please post valid JSON or Python code.

Comment: Yes JSON string

Comment: there are multiple ways to parse json, if you want to do by code be more specific. You want all first indices of every dict or just the three mentioned ones.

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
“Do my homework exercise” is not a Stack Overflow issue.  We expect you to make an honest attempt, and *then* ask a *specific* question about your algorithm or technique.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing documentation and tutorials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have corrected your JSON string to this equivalent valid JSON string:

```
{
   "list":[
      {
         "a":1,
         "b":2,
         "c":3,
         "d":{
            "d1":10,
            "d2":20,
            "d3":30
         },
         "e":4,
         "f":5,
         "g":[
            {
               "g1":100,
               "g2":200,
               "g3":300
            }
         ],
         "h":6
      }
   ]
}
```

```
import json

# some JSON:
x = '{"list":[{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":{"d1":10,"d2":20,"d3":30},"e":4,"f":5,"g":[{"g1":100,"g2":200,"g3":300}],"h":6}]}'

# parse x:
d = json.loads(x)

print(d["list"][0]["d"]["d1"])
print(d["list"][0]["e"])
print(d["list"][0]["g"][0]["g1"])
print(d["list"][0]["h"])
```

Comment: Please [accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if it solved your problem :)

Answer (score 1):

Your question is lacking a lot of informations.
Let's suppose your overall dict is called dictionnary. To access :

d1 : `dictionnary['list'][0]['d']['d1']`

e : `dictionnary['list'][0]['e']`

g1 : `dictionnary['list'][0]['g'][0]['g1']`

h : `dictionnary['list'][0]['h']`